# Unable to modify log level in samba

Tags: logs, samba, smb

`log level` is present and set to three. However I don't  see it when I do a `testparm`

and I get next to no logs (I can see restarts and about it not being able to connect to `cupsd`) which doesn't seem like `log level` is anywhere close to three, but nothing more shows up regardless of what `log level` is set to in `smb.conf`.

This isn't a terribly complicated problem but I can't figure out a way around it.

Comment: What's the version of samba? What OS? Set the `log level` to 5 and see if you notice a trace like `INFO: Current debug levels:`. Also, from the indentation of your grep seem `log level` is under some other `[section]` comment the current `log level` and move it under `[global]` (also `log file`)

Comment: `testparm -v` show your current [printing](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#PRINTING)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YMMV but with my version of samba (3.6.23) setting the log level works.

```
[global]
log level = 10
```

From the log.smbd:

```
[2014/05/16 17:10:23,  5] ../lib/util/debug.c:330(debug_dump_status)
  INFO: Current debug levels:
    all: 10
```

However, you cannot use testparm to test this because it forces the log level to 2. From the source (./source3/utils/testparm.c):

```
370 lp_set_cmdline("log level", "2")
```

In fact it looks like many of the utilities override the log level. I don't know why.

Edit: Try setting it to 10.